# How can I use jsTestDriver in jetBrains?

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, jetbrains-ide, js-test-driver

I am new to unit testing, please explain me how can I use unit testing specially jsTestDriver or karma in jetBrains software.

I saw this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/11.0/run-debug-configuration-jstestdriver.html#d157190e138) and install jsTestDriver Pluging to my phpStorm but I didn't understand how use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the response maybe helpful for others :


1.In Jetbrains software press Ctrl+Alt+s and in plugins tab install karma plugin ([Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/11.0/run-debug-configuration-jstestdriver.html#d157190e138))

2.In your project `$npm install karma --save-dev`([karma](https://karma-runner.github.io))

3.Create a config file named : karma.conf.js

4.In Jetbrains software : Run > Edit configurations > + > karma > in configuration file section select karma.conf.js 

5.You can run this and test your app